# Requesting Camera permissions on Android in Java missing imports

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am only finding incomplete or non-functional answers to this question.

For an answer, I need the code and all of the associated imports at the top of the source code in Java, please

If there are needed dependencies, please mention what file to add them to and where

I am trying to follow this tutorial, but I cannot use those imports statements, they are missing
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/android-how-to-request-permissions-in-android-application/

[image]

Comment: That tutorial is very, very outdated (android.support hasn't existed for almost 5 years). Have you tried follow the [official guidance](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need this

```
val requestPermissionLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission()
    ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            //handle
        } else {
            // not granted
        }
    }
```

This code snippet demonstrates the recommended process to check for a permission and to request a permission from the user when necessary:

```
when {
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            CONTEXT,
            Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
        // You can use the API that requires the permission.
    }

    else -> {
        // You can directly ask for the permission.
        // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
        requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.REQUESTED_PERMISSION)
    }
}
```

Follow the official tutorial for complete code https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#kotlin