# OpenCV not getting proper Confidence values in Java

Tags: python, java, android, opencv

I am following this tutorial, however my code is in Java for Android and the tutorial is in Python
https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/11/object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/

I had to convert the code, but it seems to be getting incorrect values for Confidence. Very likely because I did not do the conversion correctly.

This is the original code in Python

```
# loop over the detections
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
        # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
        # the object
        idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
        box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
        # display the prediction
        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
        print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            COLORS[idx], 2)
        y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
        cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)
```

This is my converted Java code

```
        float confidenceThreshold = 0.8f;
        // loop over the detections
        for (int i = 0; i < detections.rows(); i++) {
            // extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
            // prediction
            double confidence = detections.get(i, 2)[0];
            // filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
            // greater than the minimum confidence
            if (confidence > confidenceThreshold) {
                // extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
                // then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
                // the object
                int idx = (int)detections.get(i, 1)[0];
                int boxX = (int)(detections.get(i, 3)[0] * input_image.cols());
                int boxY = (int)(detections.get(i, 4)[0] * input_image.rows());
                int boxWidth = (int)(detections.get(i, 5)[0] * input_image.cols()) - boxX;
                int boxHeight = (int)(detections.get(i, 6)[0] * input_image.rows()) - boxY;
                // display the prediction
                Imgproc.putText(input_image, imgLabels.get((int) idx) + ": " + String.format("%.2f", confidence * 100) + "%", new Point(boxX, boxY - 5), Imgproc.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
                Imgproc.rectangle(input_image, new Point(boxX, boxY), new Point(boxX + boxWidth, boxY + boxHeight), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            }
        }
```

I am getting negative values for confidence, and other values like `idx` dont look right either.
Im not familiar enough with Python or Java syntax to see what I am doing wrong.
If someone can help spot the mistake, please answer with properly converted code.

Thank you

Comment: Please follow your own [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75570055/295004) and add imports to each section of code. Not knowing where the `detections` object comes from means readers can only guess (even if you are linking to an article).

Comment: detections is an OpenCV Mat